# Pass non-volatile variable's address to a volatile object pointer

Tags: c, atomic, volatile

Suppose I have the following function:

```
void atomic_add(volatile unsigned * loc, unsigned incr );
```

And I have want to pass a variable to the first argument of this function.

```
unsigned a;
atomic_add(&a, 1);

volatile unsigned b;
atomic_add(&b, 1);
```

From [volatile type qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile), it should can be compiled.
Q1: Do both of them get the same results?
Q2: Does the pointer returned from `mmap()` can also be used as the first argument of this function?
Thanks!

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one tag and delete the other.

Comment: Be careful with `volatile` and `atomic`.  `volatile` and `atomic` are not the same thing.  `volatile` provides no guarantees about atomicity or visibility of operations.  See [**Why is volatile not considered useful in multithreaded C or C++ programming?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484980/why-is-volatile-not-considered-useful-in-multithreaded-c-or-c-programming)

Comment: Also [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535118) - just use `std::atomic` in normal C++11 and later code-bases.  There's generally nothing to gain from `volatile` - with the right `memory_order`, `std::atomic` can compile to the same asm as code using `volatile`, if you're worried about efficiency.

Comment: @AndrewHenle In fact, this function comes from QNX doc: https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/a/atomic_add.html

Comment: @PeterCordes I want to use the atomic object in shared memory for IPC. I'm not sure C++11 atomic can be used in this scenario. I have to used the OS level's API or `boost::ipc_atomic`.

Comment: `std::atomic<T>` is usable in shared memory when it's lock-free.  Check `is_always_lock_free`.  (The ISO standard says they "should" be address-free because of this use-case, and that's the case on real implementations.)  Non-lock-free atomics are *not* safe in shared memory.  See [C++ share atomic\_int64\_t between different process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72714020) / [Atomic access to shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8759429) / [Do I use atomic<> over shared memory correctly here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73476133). This question about `volatile` seems like an XY problem.

Comment: Oh, this question is about C.  Your previous comment mentioned C++11 instead of C11 `stdatomic.h`.  Fortunately, C11 `stdatomic` stuff works the same as C++11 `std::atomic`.  They use the same compiler internals, at least on mainstream compilers like GCC and Clang.  I don't know what `atomic_add` function you're talking about.  If it's safe on shared memory, it probably doesn't need `volatile`.  If it's not, `volatile` won't help.  The C11 function is called `atomic_fetch_add`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification @PeterCordes. So I can directly use `std::atomic` in shared memory for IPC?

Comment: Yes, that's what I just said, and what the Q&As I linked say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Different between volatile pointer pointing to volatile variable and
> non-volatile variable

1. First of all `loc` is not a **`volatile pointer`**. It is a pointer referencing a *`volatile object`*
2. You can pass `volatile` and not `volatile` to this function, bout localy in the function your ocject will be treated as `volatile`. It means that it will be read before every use, and saved to its storage after every change. It will not be "buffered" in he registers. Even if you `*loc + *loc` the referenced object will be read twice.

To have a volatile pointer you need to declare it different way:

```
unsigned * volatile loc; // volatile pointer to not volatile unsigned int object
volatile unsigned * volatile loc; // volatile pointer to volatile unsigned int object
volatile unsigned * loc; // non volatile pointer to volatile unsigned int object
```

Q1 - yes

Q2 - yes